# How to save a cookie in an Android webview forever?

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview, cookiestore

With my code below, I have been able to save a cookie, but as soon as I close the application the cookie disappears.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
package com.jkjljkj

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getBaseContext());

        // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
        // browser app does.


        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);


        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity activity = this;
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
             // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
             activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
      });

      webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

         public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
              //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
              Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      });

      CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
      CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

     //This will load the webpage that we want to see
      webview.loadUrl("http://");

   }
}
```

Comment: CookieSyncManager is now deprecated, use CookieManager.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502411/cookiesyncmanager-is-now-deprecated-what-can-i-use-instead

Comment: @Rahul Sahni I tried that but if close the app and re open i have to re login and all cookies lost! Could you tell me what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to tell the CookieSyncManager to sync *after* it has loaded the page in question. In your sample code, the `onCreate` method executes completely before the `WebView` tries to load the page, so the sync process (which happens asynchronously) will probably complete before the page is loaded.

Instead, tell the CookieSyncManager to sync onPageFinished in the WebViewClient. That should get you what you want.

The [CookieSyncManager Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) is a good read for how to do this properly.

Here is how you could set up your WebViewClient implementation to do this for you:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }
);
```

You would not need to tell the CookieSyncManager to sync elsewhere with this in place. I haven't tested this, so let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm completely new... Can you give me some actual code? That would help a ton!

Comment: There you go. Give it a whirl.

Comment: I love how programmers get along :D
Cheers mates

Comment: One question, couldn't you just do this with JavaScript?

Comment: For everyone coming here and using an API later than 20. The CookieSyncManager is no longer needed and is deprecated. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) The cookies are now synced automagically.

Comment: @ Daan Pape . As you mentioned cookies are now synced automatically but when i close the app and re open i have to re login to page again on webview ! do you know what causes this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

.sync() is to force a imediate sync  ,and must be called after page load cause it sync RAM with cache , so cookie must be in ram before calling it .

System automatically sync it every 5 mintues if you use this scheme

```
onCreate: 
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context)

onResume:
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync()

onPause:
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync()
```

I think you did not waited 5 mintues so system save cookie.

Comment: What should i do If i want to sync cookies immediately without waiting 5 min on android 6?

Answer (score 5):

For those who are facing Problems with `CookieManager` class to make cookie persist even after closing the app, they should try the `flush()` function of `CookieManager`.

Please note that i haven't tried this, so if it works then please let me know too.

According to android documentation

> [void flush()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#flush())
>
> Ensures all cookies currently accessible through the getCookie API are written to persistent storage. This call will block the caller until it is done and may perform I/O.

Also in `CookieSyncManager` documnentation it is written that:

> This class was deprecated in API level 21.
> The WebView now automatically syncs cookies as necessary. You no longer need to create or use the CookieSyncManager. To manually force a sync you can use the CookieManager method flush() which is a synchronous replacement for sync(). [CookieSyncManger link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html)

Answer (score 3):

Works perfectly for API 20+

```
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url){
                CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
            }

        }
        
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for API 20+

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
         ......
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url){
                CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
            }
         ......

        }
        
        );
```

Comment: Your solution let me take a breath. Thanks Arpit