# Is there a way to retain a selected cookies from webview in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: cookies, webview, xamarin.android

I have the xamarin.android app, inwhich I load a web page into a webview. Here I want to retain a selected cookies, to reuse after killing and relaunching the app. Now my expectation is, if I feed the retained cookie the webpage should be loaded according to the cookie fed to the webview. Is there a way to retain the selected cookies?

Comment: There is a similar problem, you can check it here: [Cookie not saving in Web view in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637361/cookie-not-saving-in-web-view-in-xamarinandroid).