# Can we save login data in android WebView?

Tags: android, authentication, webview

My website needs to be logged in to use it, so is there a way to save login data for the users so they will not log in every time they enter the `WebView`, like firebase, or cookies, etc?
If you need to share my code, please let me know.

Thank you.

**Edit 1:**

This is MainActivity.java file code:

```
package com.company.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            WebAction();
        }
    });

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
    ws.setSaveFormData(true);
    ws.setSavePassword(true); // Not needed for API level 18 or greater (deprecated)


    WebAction();



}

public void WebAction(){

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }


    String myURL = "https://www.myURL.com/";

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
    ws.setSaveFormData(true);
    ws.setSavePassword(true); // Not needed for API level 18 or greater (deprecated)


    webView.loadUrl(myURL);
    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);

            findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

    });

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: To be clear, you have a `WebView` in your app that the user uses to access your website right?

Comment: Yes, I use webView in my app.

Comment: From my understanding, `WebViews` now automatically persist cookies so could you just implement using cookies like what most websites would do for storing login sessions?

Comment: I add a code to the app to accept cookies but it does not work.

Comment: I will add the code to the question so you can take a look if something wrong.

Comment: I was looking at the docs (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34892588/394933) for `CookieSyncManager` and it looks like you might need to call some `startSync()` method to make things work? Alternatively, if you're using API 21+ after they deprecated `CookieSyncManager`, it looks like you can use the `CookieManager` singleton to also force syncing, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34892588/394933. Does that help?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, Your settings works for me by the way :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

We just need to add `this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` along with `this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`.

Now we can delete the cookies codes, and save data and logins.

**EDIT:**
If it doesn't work, try not to delete the cookies code.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: "Now we can delete the cookies codes, and save data and logins" Can you explain more, please? After closing your Hybrid app in android and run it again is saved cookies exit?

Comment: I used the above but Its not working for me..can you please suggest me any better way..

Answer (score 0):

try to get values by javascript injection

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.loadUrl(
                "javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var element = document.getElementById('hplogo');"
                    + "element.parentNode.removeChild(element);" +
                "})()");
        }
    });
```