# Remember User Credentials In Android WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView App which opens a website's login page as its first page ! and now I want to Save User's Login Information So They Don't Have to Put their Credentials Every Time they Open The app but because of some security issues I don't want to keep users logged in after they kill the app !!
How can I do this ??
Thank You All In Advance !

Comment: This may be help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-save-password-in-android-webview

Comment: @NobanHasan So it says adding only
`web_view.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);` would be enought ? And how about username?

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you. Add this code snippet inside your code.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

WebView webview = new WebView(this);
WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
ws.setSaveFormData(true);
ws.setSavePassword(true); 
ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Reference :https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234172/8332511

Comment: `setSavePassword` is deprecated and not working anymore !! Do You Know any other way?
@NobanHasan

Comment: Ist there any other way?