# How to maintain session in WebView after exiting the application in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-cookiemanager

I'm currently new to Android development but I'm trying to create a simple android app that opens up my website and allows you to log into it in WebView. However, I realized that when you exit the application and terminate its process and relaunch the application, it asks you to re-log back in, instead of staying logged in. I'm not sure how to go about to solve this issue. I've looked into the implementation of CookieManager, however, I'm not able to get that to work correctly. Could you help show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        cookieManager.acceptCookie();
        String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("myWebsite");
        myWebView.loadUrl("myWebsite");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

Comment: Did you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234172/5571202

Comment: I've went ahead and tried that solution, but unfortunately it did not work. I really appreciate the comment and help though. I think the problem is that the website currently checks if you have a cookie session to know to log you in automatically. However, I think that when I terminate the app all the cookie sessions are lost but I'm not fully sure how to fix that or to test that idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same trouble.

Try to setup the `WebviewSettings` like so:

```java
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

And flush the cookies from the in memory database to the persistent memory.

```java
CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
```

After the flush, the cookies should exist even after a full app-relaunch.

Access the Cookies using:

```java
CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(yourUrlString)
```