# I need to persist a login even after a WebView app is closed (android)

Tags: android, session-cookies

I am trying to edit my android application so that the user does not need to log in after they have logged in once, even if they close the application.

I have been referencing this link below:

[How to save a cookie in an android webview forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390156/how-to-save-a-cookie-in-an-android-webview-forever)

as well as the official documentation, but I just am not "getting" how to do this. Can anyone help me in understanding what I need to do?

here is my code: 
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

     // Enable Javascript
     WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     mWebView.loadUrl("https://app.dhanvapasi.com");
    }
```

Comment: Clarified question for native English speakers. cleaned up the formatting, and expanded the description of what you are looking for.

You now need to explain what you have tried, and what results you have achieved, including code examples and any errors that you are getting, so that people can help you with your current knowledge. If there is nothing in the question that says what you tried, no one will know where to start explaining things to you.

Thanks!

Comment: what i want to do is fairly simple , i need to render an existing webapp in a webview but i want the logged in user to be logged in even after app is closed .