# cookies created by webpage in android webview is getting deleted after app closes

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview, session-cookies

I'm working on webpage of an andriod webview app, and creating the cookies in `React.js`, it's working fine in desktop, but when testing it inside the app, it's deleting cookies saved after app closes.

```
setCookie("login", true, 1);
setCookie("tokenId", responseJson.data.tokenId, 30);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390280/3479012 might help?